# Using cryptography is it possible for offline devices to reliably communicate via QR code?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I really thought of posting this question on IOT forum. But it's very much about cryptography and its limits so here goes..

What I want:

- Imagine there is a set of vending machines, they are not connected to internet, but can be updated monthly.
- User buys tokens when online, and then tokens live on user's app/phone.
- User goes to vending machine and shows machine the token.
- And machine lets user buy the items.
- User shouldn't be able to use the same token at any other machine, or at this machine. Even though none are connected to internet.

One possible approach I brainstormed...

- Machine comes with 9 trillion builtin tokens.
- There are multiple machines with same token, all machines have the same set of tokens.
- User pays through an app when he has an internet and gets a special token..
- User comes to machine, scan his token in QR form and then machine knows if user has paid or not, without internet by searching in its database.
- Once user has used the token it doesn't work on any other machine, (not sure how)

however it has flaws...

1. Once token is used I dont know how other machines could know that token has been used, I can't simply rely on an app to remove token as it can be altered? or user could simply screenshot the QR token.
2. Someone can crack open the vending machine and get 2 trillion tokens? no? if i encrypt tokens then somehow this would work?

Basically I had this idea for hackathon and ever since I've been interested in this problem, to communicate offline.

Comment: In a debit system you can simply bill tokens which are spent multiple times. You would use challenge/response signing to guarantee non-reputation. In a pre-paid System, especially if it should be anonymous that’s harder. I know there are some protocols which share commonalities with voting systems (detecting fraud with high probability), but Imam not sure about a good paper or implementation. The easiest I guess is having the machine beeing offline but the payment app to request a token from online server.

Comment: Is the phone expected to be online?

Comment: at some point, but not necessarily when it's near the vending machine

Comment: Are the items in the machine all priced differently? That is common for snack vending machines, but not for say a soda vending machine. If they are all priced the same, then it is much easier. For example, 1 token = 1 can of soda is much easier than 1 token = a variable amount of money and the user must have exact "change".

Comment: assume same price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is fundamentally impossible. While *some* of it can be achieved (and rather easily), *some* is simply not possible. If it was possible, and you had found a solution, you would instantly be elegible for the Nobel prize (indeed, the committee would invent the Nobel prize in Awesomeness just for you).

Why am I saying that?

The requirement *"cannot buy again at a different vending machine [that isn't connected]"* basically means that a different vending machine instantly knows, by means of magic or divination, that a token has been used.
Imagine what NASA would say about such an invention. Or any of the leading telecommunication companies. Instant communication to anywhere and everywhere, and who cares whether the Moon is in the way.

It is trivial to prevent token reuse on the same machine (simply remember them). If you contrain tokens so they only work on one machine, that would provide a solution to the reuse-on-other-machine, but this is much undesirable.

It is also pretty trivial to prevent using a whole bag full of stolen tokens, simply by not making it possible to steal them (because there is nothing to steal).

It is, within limits, possible to prevent a single person (without accomplice) from reusing a token on another machine if machines are sufficiently far apart and there is a sufficient number of legitimate users.

Everything else is, unluckily, sheer impossible.

Let's make some assumptions:

1. Your tokens are at their core simple monotonically increasing 64 bit numbers. 64 bits are enough for any amount of things you might want to sell during the next couple of weeks.
2. Each token further contains an Ed25519 signature, so you cannot just present *any* random 64 bit number to the machine. Each machine possesses the public key, but there's nothing on the machine that is worth stealing. Well, you *can* steal the public key, but you're not going to make valid tokens with that!
3. Each vending machine can trivially verify that you present a valid token (the signature is valid). That's 320 bits (40 bytes) of information in total which you have to store in your QR code.
4. After each purchase, the machine remembers the 64-bit number as "has been cached in" -- preferrably on permanent store, and before handing out the goods, so you can't just pull the electric plug. Of course you can still use an axe and smash the machine to bits (destroying the information) but then you can *always* do that and steal the goods right away.
5. With your legitimate purchase, without knowing, you *also* transmit a list of sequence numbers (with a single signature for the whole block) that have been used at other machines, and have been communicated back via the regular offline means. A typical QR code can hold anywhere from 500 to 1000 bytes of binary data (close to 3000 if you press it to the max), so you could easily piggy-back anywhere from 50 to 100 used tokens on your QR code -- per purchase. In order to prevent users from sabotaging the system by presenting a selfmade QR code that only contains their token, have the machine only accept a token if also a valid (if empty) list of used tokens is included.
6. As an optimization, you can remember the lowest sequence number below which all numbers have been cashed in. Unluckily, someone might do an online purchase and never use the token (so you'd have holes in your sequence), but it is possible to just let them expire after some time. Similar is done for example with your balance on many pre-paid phones which is just "gone" no matter what after a year or two. People seem to accept that, no problem.

But could that work at all? Sure...

Imagine there is a set of data storage mediums which, for an unspecified reason, are encrypted and half of the encryption key is stored in a way so it can be deciphered by the device necessary to read said data storage medium with its own built-in key. Imagine newer data storage mediums regularly need newer versions of said keys, and leaked keys are regularly disabled either via online firmware updates or side channels (stored on a medium that you insert). You probably have such a medium as well as the device to read it in your home.

So, in short, yes this is generally possible, but only within some constraints, and only if you can tolerate some loss. The movie industry can, and does, live with that loss. And while it is a major nuisance to most legitimate users (who maybe wish to make a backup), all in all it "works" pretty well, in the intended sense.

The first obvious problem is that even with enough legitimate users communicating to the machines, communicating back only once per month is by no means enough. I could cash in my token today, and again tomorrow, on a different machine.

The second obvious problem is that even if machines are so far apart that it takes me an hour to get to the next machine, and back-communication happens once per hour, then still a customer might buy and legitimately cash in a token, and then instantly send a message to half a dozen accomplices who are at a different vending machine each. The accomplices would then make another "legitimate" transaction each, and there is nothing you can do to prevent that.

Unless you either communicate *before* handing out goods, or you have the client accept that he is charged for double cash-ins, there's nothing you can do, really. Not unless you have a solution for the magical transmission of knowledge.

Comment: Can you talk about #3 a little bit more, how?

Comment: Well, a signature algorithm can verify whether or not a message (usually the hash of a message because normally messages are much longer) is valid or not. I named a small EdDSA algo as example, but you can as well use RSA or whatever, makes no difference except size. In this case the "message" is just one 64 bit number, or rather a couple of iterations of a secure hash of that number since that puts the point on the curve on a more "random" location. leaving fewer predictable bit patterns that could be exploited easily. If the signature matches, you proceed. If it does not, you bail out.

Comment: The nice property of signature algorithms (or public key algos in general) is that you need not fear someone stealing your public key. It's not something you need to keep secret. Someone in possesion of the key can verify whether a token is valid (so what!), but without the secret key (that you keep under your pillow or on a chain around your neck, figuratively speaking) they cannot _create_ them. So there is really nothing to be stolen.

Answer (score 1):

While it is generally possible to create a lightweight data structure that can be signed by the payment server (using an internal CA for example which is preloaded on the accepting devices) - and you could work against the reuse problem by having the accepting machine “cross off“ the previously accepted IDs, there are some things that are simply not possible without communication.

You would have to define the accepting devices ID on time of purchase to make sure it gets only used on that device to prohibit reuse on other devices. From your question I can not see that that is acceptable.

And then there’s a practical problem: having a data structure that holds enough information for the payload and the signature will make it hard to convey via optical codes. You suggested QR codes, which get hard to read with about 20 bytes of data - your signature alone will exceed that by far.

Comment: QR codes can hold quite much data. Here is an example containing the last paragraph of the answer: https://cdn.rawgit.com/suterma/quirli/1.1.0/website/qr.frameable.inline.html?text=And%20then%20there%E2%80%99s%20a%20practical%20problem:%20having%20a%20data%20structure%20that%20holds%20enough%20information%20for%20the%20payload%20and%20the%20signature%20will%20make%20it%20hard%20to%20convey%20via%20optical%20codes.%20You%20suggested%20QR%20codes,%20which%20get%20hard%20to%20read%20with%20about%2020%20bytes%20of%20data%20-%20your%20signature%20alone%20will%20exceed%20that%20by%20far.

Comment: I have written and deployed application that uses digitally signed data exchange through a QRCode: it definitely possible to do so in a practical manner as long as you don't include the certificate with the signature and don't have too much data in the cleartext

Comment: So i read little bit about blockchain, and i feel there is a way to do something here without having machines to be able to communicate with each other directly.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer sure, if you can create a ledger and have all machines access it, you’d be fine. But that sounds like communication, other than every few months. If you have that, you can just use a centralized ledger, i.e. a web service on a server.

Comment: ah i see, yea communication is the problem

Comment: the more info in qrcodes, the harder it is to scan, aggravated by low light, moving cameras, old phones, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One of this must be true for offline payments to be possible:

1. Use a dedicated payment smartcard, rather than user's phone. This is called [Stored Value card](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored-value_card). The assumption here is that an attacker would need to tamper with the smartcard to trick the system. Well designed stored value card is quite difficult to tamper, though it's not impossible, so you'll have to include that possibility as a calculated business risk.
2. Make it at least partially post paid. Use asymmetric crypto to allow the user to issue as many tokens as they want for themselves, but all the tokens are tied to their own account. The user's device may stop issuing token when the user ran out of credit, but this isn't strictly necessary for security. The vending machine should record which token are used, and at the end of the billing period, you collate transactions from all machines and if the user's transaction exceeds the amount they have prepaid, you charge the additional amount on the user. Since you need to be able to collect the extra payments, this likely means you will have to hold on to a valid credit card or sufficient personal identification that allows you to collect the debts when necessary.

Comment: When you think about it, #2 is essentially how credit card used to work when they used the manual card imprinting machine.